# Angular 6 upgrade: debounceTime is not property of Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am attempting to upgrade my app from Angular 5 to Angular 6. I followed the steps on the https://update.angular.io/
At least i think i did.

The Error is :

```
Property 'debounceTime' does not exist on type 'Subject<string>'.
```

Also my components lost the debounceTime import. I think the ng update removed it.

Comment: did you do the import like this: import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators' ?

Comment: Yeah. I added this statement : 

import { map, takeUntil, tap, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Also, did you piped the operator instead of chained?

Comment: Are you using `subject.debounceTime(...)` or `subject.pipe(debounceTime(...))` syntax?

Comment: just straight up     this.field$.debounceTime(400)

Comment: It should be this.field$.pipe(debounceTime(400))

Comment: ah,  would it be something like this? 
   this.userName$.pipe(
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe(term => {

Comment: this.userName$.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged())

this isn't causing an error

Comment: Yup, RxJS is moving away from the dot chaining in v6. @Logan_B looks correct...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved it with the help of @Siva636 and @Andrew Lobban.

I needed to use pipe:

```
  this.field$.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged())
```

Comment: @Logan_B I din't upgrade since. I still run the old version. I can't remember the error

Answer (score 10):

As of Angular 6.1.8, just need to import and add pipe like below example

```html
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then on field just before the observable subscribe method call pipe(debounceTime(1000)) like below:

```html
emailControl.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(value => this.setMessage(emailControl));
```

And that's it, it's just a updated answers of @tiago's answer - where she is defining const debouncetime - we don't really need to use const and pipe.

Answer (score 6):

Following the reactivex docs, you should also subscribe to the pipe observable :

```
.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map((val) => {
        ...
    })
)
.subscribe();
```

[An Observable is called a “cold” Observable if it does not begin to emit items until an observer has subscribed to it.](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html)

Answer (score 1):

i am sorry for the delay but i just get this problem today and fixed like this.
i solve this issue like this:
first import like this:

```
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {pipe} from 'rxjs'
```

Then create a const like this (i tried to do directly without duplicating pipe but didn´t work so i found this solution):

```
const debouncetime = pipe(debounceTime(1000));
```

And then use it before you subscribe for example i was doing an email validator with messages:

```
const emailControl = this.registerForm.get('email');
    emailControl.valueChanges
     .pipe(debouncetime)
     .subscribe(value => this.setEmailMessage(emailControl))
```

dont know if its the best solutions but it works perfectly.
I hope it helps some one!

Comment: No need for the debouncetime variable, just do
    .pipe(debounceTime(1000))