# How to properly use mat-autocomplete with remote graphQL data?

Tags: angular, graphql, ngrx, apollo, mat-autocomplete

I am using angular 6 here with angular material and I'm trying to build a search component that uses graphQL with Apollo.

well, the component works, but I would like to address these issues:

1. I want to add debounceTime and I can't find exactly where to add it.
2. I want that empty values won't be searched in the graphQL query
3. I don't use async filter for mat-autocomplete since I put the results inside an array. is that the correct way to go?

My product service that interacts with the graphQL server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Apollo} from 'apollo-angular';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

  searchForProduct(productName: string) {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
    query: gql`{products_by_p_name_search(lang_id:1,query:"${productName}")
    {category_id,price,category_name,id,name,desc,quantity,year_manufacture,image_file}}`
    });
  }
}
```

my search component html with the `mat-autocomplete` component:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="חפש מוצר" aria-label="חפש מוצר" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="productCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.name">
        <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden src="../../assets/products/{{product.id}}/{{product.imgFile}}_t.jpg" height="25">
        <span>{{product.name}}</span> |
        <small>Population: {{product.population}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And finally my search component (Typescript file):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Product} from '../product';
import {ProductService} from '../product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-product',
  templateUrl: './search-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-product.component.scss']
})
export class SearchProductComponent implements OnInit {
  productCtrl = new FormControl();
  products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.productCtrl.valueChanges
      .subscribe(v => {
        this.productService.searchForProduct(v.toString()).valueChanges.subscribe(
          ({data}) => {
            const productsResult: Product[] = [];
            data.products_by_p_name_search.forEach((productObj) => {
                const product = new Product();
                product.id = productObj.id;
                product.categoryName = productObj.category_name;
                product.name = productObj.name;
                product.desc = productObj.desc;
                product.quantity = productObj.quantity;
                product.yearManufacture = productObj.year_manufacture;
                product.imgFile = productObj.image_file;
                product.categoryId = productObj.category_id;
                product.price = productObj.price;
                productsResult.push(product);
              });
            this.products = productsResult;
          });
      });
  }
}
```

As far as i see, these lines of code can work, but it might not be the most optimized way to write it. so any information regarding the issues above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to add debounceTime and I can't find exactly where to add it.

You add debounce time[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191318/angular-6-upgrade-debouncetime-is-not-property-of-subject)]where you subscribe to value updates. Your `ngOnInit` will look something like this

```
ngOnInit() {
this.productCtrl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(v => {
  ...
```

Don't forget to `import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';`.

> I want that empty values won't be searched in the graphQL query

throw a `filter( value => value.length > 0)`

Your `ngOnInit` is now something like

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.productCtrl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter( value => value.length > 0)
    )
    .subscribe(v => {
 ...
```

> I don't use async filter for mat-autocomplete since I put the results inside an array. is that the correct way to go?

I don't know your reasoning behind not using async pipe. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670236/7049436) has a working demo of pipe.